# How to get difference in hour using Java

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jakarta-ee

I have two dates with me and I am trying to extract delta of hours from it -

```
 Date1 = "2014-03-22 22:00:00.022023"
 Date2= "2014-03-26 16:45:04.445531"
```

The above two dates are in timestamp and I am getting it from postgresql database. Now I am trying to extract delta of hours between the above two dates. So I have below code -

```
     long delta =  getDateDiff(queryDate, createdDate, TimeUnit.HOURS);
     System.out.println(delta);

     public static long getDateDiff(Date date1, Date date2, TimeUnit timeUnit) {
     long diffInHour = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
     return TimeUnit.convert(diffInHour,TimeUnit.HOURS);
   }
```

But the delta is coming as - `326704423` which is wrong as it should come as `91 hour`. I also have similar SQL query which gives me the delta of hour between the dates and from that I can see 91 as the answer coming back so something wrong I am doing for sure.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: How is `TimeUnit` supposed to know that number is in milliseconds? Just divide it by 3600000.0.

Comment: Thanks @chrylis, you are right It worked. Can you post that as an answer so that I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getTime()` returns a number of milliseconds.  So you need to convert the milliseconds to hours.

```
public static long getDateDiff(Date date1, Date date2) {
    long diffInMilliseconds = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
    return TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(diffInMilliseconds);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

update your function to

```
public static long getDateDiff(Date date1, Date date2, TimeUnit timeUnit) {
  return (long) ((date2.getTime() - date1.getTime())/3600000);
}
```